# How to determine the maximum amount of memory cached while running Spark job?

Tags: memory, apache-spark

Can anyone tell me how to determine the maximum amount of memory cached while running Spark job? I need this to show the performance (memory utilization) of my algorithm for various input sizes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are some metrices which are exposed by Spark via REST API's for the running and completed jobs

1. http://:4040/api/v1 - for Running Applications
2. http://:18080/api/v1 - for completed applications, only if your history server is configured.

Here are 2 API's which may help you: -

1. /applications/[app-id]/storage/rdd - Provides list of stored RDDs
   for the given application.
2. /applications/[app-id]/storage/rdd/[rdd-id]-    Details for the storage
   status of a given RDD.

Refer to Spark Doc for all exposed REST endpoints - http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html